# How to style a Cocoa Application title bar?

Tags: swift, cocoa

How do I style the title bar of a Cocoa application, much like the way Twitter.app does? Example:

[image]

Comment: Tip: Borderless

Answer (score 1):

*For the transparent titleBar:* 
There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1. Approach (Easiest):
   Set your window to be a textured `window`. It will get a grey gradient as background, as the `titleBar` disappears.
   Then you can set the `backgroundColor` (for example from `windowContoller`) to your preferred color.

   ```
   self.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.darkGray
   ```
2. Approach (More flexible):
   You may want to have a little more flexibility . To replicate exactly Twitters design the first approach would not work.
   To make the title bar transparent by calling

   ```
   self.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
   ```

   Then you have to set the window to have a full size content view. This makes the `contentView` of the window to begin directly at the windows `frame` (0 ,0). You have to watch out for this as your views may appear under the `titleBar`. Set `window.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor` as the minimum space between your windows content and the top of the view.
   You get further information on this from this years [Crafting Modern Cocoa Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/239/) WWDC session.

*For the more entered buttons:* 
So now you have a transparent title bar. To get the button effect you need to add a toolbar to your window. As you do not want to have any items in there, you can remove them all. 
In code you just need to set

```
self.window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
```

and the buttons will align with the invisible toolbar. You can make the look perfect by disabling the separator of the toolbar.